# I am unable to use echo and cat in this simple device driver module.

Tags: c, device, linux-device-driver, drivers

```
    static ssize_t device_read (struct file* filp, char *bufStoreData, size_t bufCount, loff_t* curOffset)
    {
      printk(KERN_INFO"reading from the device");
      ret = copy_to_user(bufStoreData,virtual_device.data,bufCount);
      return ret;
    }

    static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp,const char* bufSourceData,size_t bufCount, loff_t* curOffset)
    {
      printk(KERN_INFO"writing to device");
      ret=copy_from_user(virtual_device.data,bufSourceData,bufCount);
      return ret;
    }
```

I was using echo and cat command to do the user write and read but i was not reading the data properly. Maybe i am not returning right values.Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

`device_read()` and `device_write()` return value is the number of read/written bytes. `copy_to_user()` and `copy_from_user()` return `0` if all bytes were copied, otherwise the numer of bytes not copied.

Probably your operation succeed and you are returning `0`, which means "0 byte copied".

You must return `bufCount` on success and a negative error code on fail.

```
ret=copy_from_user(virtual_device.data,bufSourceData,bufCount);
if (ret)
    return ret;

return bufCount;
```

Comment: `copy_{to,from}_user}` do not return an error code; they return the number of bytes *not* copied (which is `0` on success). If the `copy_...` function returns a non-zero result, the function should probably return `-EINVAL`.

Comment: the thing is i am getting N INFINITE amount of outout on terminal...how to control it?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, you are right :) Fast answer without think, I edit my answer

Comment: @mrigendra did you fix your module? Or it is a new issue?

Comment: its not a new issue i am having this problemm for 2 days now, and i think the problem is in returning, but i can't figure out how to manage it...

Comment: printing only stops when driver knows that it work is over, how did it knows that it has outputted all the bytes that is to be printed?if i return bfcount it will print that requested amount of bytes continuosly and if i return ret that is 0 so nothing will be printed.

Comment: You wrote a continuous read program, and it works great if it outputs forever: it is what you wrote. `cat` is a program that read until `EOF`, you wrote a driver that outputs data every time. So you are outputting data forever.